# Android - Email

Tags: java, android, email

I was wondering what is the easiest way to send an email from my app.

I basically, have a page with 2 TextViews and 2 EditText boxes in which I need to get the information to send within the email.

I also, have a EditText box which contains the users email address.

I need to then send an email to the user using the enterered email address and grabbing the rest of the information on this page on a button click.

I have looked and tried various things, however nothing seems to work. Could some point me in the right direction or provide a detailed tutorial explaining the whole process from start to finish.

Finally, will this only work on an actual device (which is connected to the internet)?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just for future reference, you need to accept correct answers to your questions or else no one will want to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "some@email.address" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

It will only work on an actual device.

Comment: This code will work with or without Internet connection, so no Exception or anything when no internet. But obviously you can't send the mail without internet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code fragment I use to send email. Note that this method is not automatic, it will display a list of application you can choose from (default email, gmail, sms, evernote, spring pad etc).

```
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Message");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a test message");
    Uri attachment = null;
    if (mAttachHTML && (attachment = writeToExternalStoragePublic()) != null) {
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.reporting_sharemessage)));
```

This method doesn't seem to work for me in the emulator but works perfectly on the device.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to send an email is firing an `Intent` to do that, as opposed to implementing your own email-sending functionality.

You can do that by firing an `android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND` `Intent` with the extra fields configured to the email fields. More specifically;

`Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL`: the destination address

`Intent.EXTRA_CC`: the copy address, if any

`Intent.EXTRA_BCC`: the blind carbon copy address(es), if any

`Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`: the body of the email

Note that if you use `EXTRA_TEXT`, you should set the MIME type to text/plain. If you want to send another content type, you should use `EXTRA_STREAM` instead and provide the data that way.